# how to get transaction hash status & signer details using rust anchor framework

Tags: rust, anchor-lang

I want to implement a function that will take transaction hash as an input parameter, then I need to check the transaction status and signer details

Can anyone help me how I can do this or any other way to implement the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the Rust Anchor Framework, but that's only used for on-chain programs.  If you're trying to fetch a past transaction, you don't need Anchor, just the JSON RPC API.  Specifically, you can use the `getTransaction` call: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

If you're on-chain, you cannot access any past transactions.